# Adding to an existing folder in gitlab from command line

Tags: git, gitlab

Want to add a project to a folder in Gitlab which has files in it, but I'm a bit concerned that if I push my project to there I'll simply be overwriting those existing files. How can I simply add my repo or files to the folder without overwriting?

If I simply add the remote location and push to remote, I'm worried I'm going to overwrite what is already there. Do I have to clone or pull the remote repo and add files or is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, create a new project on gitlab, and modify your existed project's origin ,and push it:

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin ssh://YOUR GITLAB HOSTNAME/PROJECT NAME.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Comment: Won't this simply overwrite what is already there.